# Choosing best semantics for related variables in an untyped language like Python

Tags: python, variables, naming-conventions, typing

Consider the following situation: you work with audio files and soon there are different contexts of what "an audio" actually is in same solution.

This on one side is more obvious through typing, though while Python has classes and typing, but it is less explicit in the code like in Java. I think this occurs in any untyped language.

My question is how to have less ambiguous variable names and whether there is something like an official and widely accepted guideline or even a standard like PEP/RFC for that or comparable.

Examples for variables:

- A string type to designate the path/filename of the actual audio file
- A file handle for the above to do the I/O
- Then, in the package pydub, you deal with the type AudioSegment
- While in the package moviepy, you deal with the type AudioFileClip

Using all the four together, requires in my eyes for a clever naming strategy, but maybe I just oversee something.

Maybe this is a quite exocic example, but if you think of any other media types, this should provide a more broad view angle. Likewise, is a Document a handle, a path or an abstract object?

Answer (score 0):

There is no definitive standard/rfc to name your variables.  One option is to prefix/suffix your variables with a (possibly short form) type.  For example, you can name a variable as foo_Foo where variable foo_Foo is of type Foo.